# Array shape in python

Tags: python, numpy

This is going to be a rather silly question, though it is annoying. I have a list of 800 ndarrays which have 7680 elements each. How do I get this to a <800,7680> format ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass it to the `np.array` factory function.  As an example:

```
>>> lst = [np.zeros(7680) for x in range(800)]  #just a list of 800 ndarrays ...
>>> arr = np.array(lst)   #make them into an array
>>> arr.shape   #shape looks OK to me :-)
(800, 7680)
```